# How to easily copy/paste/clear every other column range for 100+ columns with VBA

Tags: copy, paste

I wrote a very simple code for a few columns, starting with column D. Copied values from column D14:D85 and pasted it in prior column C14:C85 and cleared the column D range. All within same sheet. However, there is like 100 plus columns, how do I simplify this code to apply to all columns in this sheet without writing column by column lines of code.

Code Example:

```
Sub Copy_EndBal_BegBal()

Range("D14:D85").Select
Selection.copy
Range("C14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("D14", "D85").ClearContents

Range("F14:F85").Select
Selection.copy
Range("E14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("F14", "F85").ClearContents

Range("H14:H85").Select
Selection.copy
Range("G14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("H14", "H85").ClearContents

Range("J14:J85").Select
Selection.copy
Range("I14").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("J14", "J85").ClearContents
```